# Не работает await функция загрузки картинок

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

В функции onSubmit нужно дождатся выполениния загрузки фото, а потом пойти дальше. Но await не работает

```js
const onSubmit = useCallback(async values => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')).userId
    uploadImage() // не срабатывает
    const adId = await axios.post(`${config.serverUrl}/api/ads`, values)
    .then(res => res.data._id)

    const adsArr = [...ads,adId]
    const saveInUser = await axios.put(`${config.serverUrl}/api/users/newAd/${user}`, adsArr)
    
    history.push('/home')
  }, [])
```

Не получается реализовать загрузку картинок в базу mongoDB. Иногда бывает по случайности сохранит и то одну картинку из массива. Не знаю в чем проблема. Может посоветуете другое решение?Это сделал...  Еще нужно добавить водяной знак при загрузке фото. Как можно это реализовать?

```js
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const imgArr = [...images]
    const formData = new FormData()

    imgArr.map(img => {
      formData.append('image', img)
    })

    const result = await Promise.resolve(axios.post(`${config.serverUrl}/api/images`,formData))
    setImgId(result.data)
  }
```

```js
ImgRouter.post('/', upload.array('image', 5), (req, res, next) => {  //принимаю картинки на nodejs, тут                                                                      тоже вроде все норм
  const images = req.files.map((file) => {
    return {
      filename: file.filename,
      originalname: file.originalname
    }
  })
  ImageModel.insertMany(images, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(404)
    res.json(result)
  })
})
```

Comment: водяной через канвас без проблем,
сабмит не асинхронная функция не стоит ждать чудес,   
по сабмиту нужно сделать event.preventDefault() думаю, 
в песочнице было бы удобнее фиксить.

Comment: добавь в запрос `axois.post` заголовки `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }` и расскажи что изменилось. я сегодня или завтра напишу развернутый пример работы с multer